# How do I get arbitrary objects to serialize as JSON in Serilog using ILogger scopes?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'm creating logs using the normal ILogger logger, and am attempting to output to Serilog.  The actual output works, but when I add an arbitrary object through `ILogger<T>.BeginScope`, it shows up in the log as `"TestApp.Program+TestLoggableType"` instead of the JSON representation.

I've got the Serilog template setup like this:

```cs
return loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
  "{ { timestamp:@t, message:@m, messageTemplate:@mt, level:@l, exception:@x, context:@p } }\n"
));
```

And here is the type I'm adding to the scope:

```cs
public class TestLoggableType
{
  public string Name { get; }
  public int Thing { get; }

  public TestLoggableType(string name, int thing)
  {
    Name = name;
    Thing = thing;
  }
}
```

And I'm adding it to the scopes like this:

```cs
Dictionary<string, object?> scopes = new()
{
  { "context", new TestLoggableType("Blah", 1) }
};

using (logger.BeginScope(scopes))
{
  logger.LogError(testException, "Error");
}
```

With all that setup, I get a log message like this:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-09-27T11:24:18.0184980-05:00","message":"Error","messageTemplate":"Error","level":"Error","exception":"System.Exception: Message","context":{"SourceContext":"Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost","context":"TestApp.Program+TestLoggableType"}}
```

I've tried setting up a user-defined function, but the property value is *already a string* by the time my function sees it, so I have no way to serialize the object.

Am I missing something?  This seems like something that should be pretty simple, but I just can't figure it out looking through the docs.  I can't give the expression template to `JsonFormatter` or anything, so I'm stumped as to how to control serialization of arbitrary types.

**EDIT**

Here is the full text of my little example project.

```cs
public record TestLoggableRecord(string Name, int Value);

public class TestLoggableType
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Thing { get; }

    public TestLoggableType(string name, int thing)
    {
        Name = name;
        Thing = thing;
    }
}

public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public object? Context { get; }
    public bool IsRetryable { get; }

    public CustomException(string message, object? context = null, bool isRetryable = false)
        : base(message)
    {
        Context = context;
        IsRetryable = isRetryable;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Exception testException = new("Message", new TestLoggableRecord("Blah", 1));
    
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseSerilog((_, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo
                    .Console(new ExpressionTemplate("{ { timestamp:@t, message:@m, messageTemplate:@mt, level:@l, exception:@x, context:@p } }\n"));
            })
            .Build();

        ILogger<IHost> logger = (ILogger<IHost>)host.Services.GetService(typeof(ILogger<IHost>))!;

        Dictionary<string, object?> scopes = new()
        {
            { "context", new TestLoggableType("Blah", 1) }
        };

        using (logger.BeginScope(scopes))
        {
            logger.LogError(testException, "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, I'm using `Serilog.Expressions/3.4.1`, `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/7.0.0`, and `Serilog.Sinks.Console/4.1.0`.

The output from this is:

```json
{"timestamp":"2023-09-27T14:10:35.2964020-05:00","message":"Error","messageTemplate":"Error","level":"Error","exception":"JsonNodeSerialize.Program+CustomException: Message","context":{"SourceContext":"Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost","context":"JsonNodeSerialize.Program+TestLoggableType"}}
```

I also just noticed that it didn't serialize the extra fields on the exception, either.

Comment: Show us your full Serilog-configuration code. What Serilog extension-packages are you using? Serilog doesn't serialize to JSON by default, you need to configure it.

Comment: I've added the full text of my tester.

The log message comes out looking like JSON.  It seems weird that it would produce _some_ of the JSON, but not all of it.

Comment: This just keeps getting weirder and weirder.  I tried writing my own little `ITextFormatter`, just to make sure that what I thought should get logged actually did, and it turns out that by the time the formatter sees the log message, the `TestLoggableType` that I added to the context is _already_ a string.  What on earth is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the key in your dictionary with an ampersand (`@`) to get Serilog to destructure the value, just like you would in a log message template:

```
Dictionary<string, object?> scopes = new()
{
    { "@context", new TestLoggableType("Blah", 1) }
};
```

I'll be darned if I can find the reference now, but I'm pretty sure it's documented *somewhere*.

Comment: Magic strings are frustrating, but that works, at least.